# Erro na leitura de valores para uma matriz alocada dinamicamente

Tags: c, matriz, alocação, malloc

Boa tarde,

Eu estou fazendo uns códigos para estudar mais sobre alocamento de memória em C com a função malloc, e estava desenvolvendo um código pra alocar uma matriz e depois ler valores e salvar nela, mas ele esta dando erro durante execução e fechando o programa, alguém poderia me ajudar e explicar o porque do erro.

Trecho de Código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int ** alocar(){
     int ** matriz;
     int i;
     matriz = (int **) malloc(3 * sizeof(int *));
     for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        matriz[i] = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
     return (&matriz);
}

void lerValores(int ** matriz){
     int i, j;
     for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
         for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
             printf("Valor[%d][%d]:", i, j);
             scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
             printf("\n");
         }
     }
}

void main()
{
    int ** matriz;
    matriz = alocar();
    lerValores(matriz);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no retorno da função `alocar`:

```
int ** alocar(){
     int ** matriz;
     int i;
     matriz = (int **) malloc(3 * sizeof(int *));
     for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        matriz[i] = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
     return (&matriz); //<-- aqui
}
```

Em que o tipo não joga com o que foi declarado. A função declara que retorna um `int**` mas a propria `matriz` é do tipo `int**` o que faz com que o endereço da `matriz` seja do tipo `int ***`. Repare que utilizou `&matriz` ou seja endereço de matriz.

Devemos sempre ter muita atenção aos avisos que o compilador dá, pois estes são quase sempre erros. No seu caso o aviso que dá ao compilar o código é o seguinte:

> ...|10|warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
>   default] ...

Que é precisamente o motivo do erro, que o tipo retornado e o tipo declarado são incompatíveis.

Para resolver basta trocar o `return` para:

```
return matriz;
```

Comment: Obrigado, realmente faz sentido, eu tinha visto um exemplo que usava & por isso usei, mas era uma coisa diferente, mas obrigado ajudou

Comment: @Isac outro coisa não seria o fato dele não ter desalocado a mémoria? Assim...não que seja um erro, mas sim uma "não boa pratica de programação".

Comment: @DC-10 É de facto um ponto relevante o que mencionou, e que eu muitas vezes alerto, mas como neste caso logo a seguir a memória ser utilizada o programa termina, acaba por não fazer diferença. Mas num cenário diferente utilizando a mesma função pode rapidamente se tornar numa fuga de memória.